# How to calculate the chance of a coin being unfair?

Tags: binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

Say I have $x$ heads out of $n$ samples/throws. Say $x>\frac n2$.

Based on the sample size $n$ and the fraction $\frac xn$ what is the probability that the coin is unfair AND unfair towards heads?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, it's just that most binomial examples seem to deal with the probability of getting say heads, but I'm interested in the confidence level that the coin is unfair towards heads.

Comment: Your question, "what is the probability that the coin is unfair" only makes sense from a Bayesian perspective.

Comment: Does the binomial test not apply here? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

"Chance of a coin being unfair" is too vague and needs to be more specific.

- The p-value of a binomial exact test is the probability of seeing more than $x$ heads *if the coin were fair*. [Alternatively you can use a normal approximation to approximate this probability (z-test).] Although this test could in principle help you detect whether the coin is unfair towards heads, it isn't really "the probability that the coin is unfair."
- In the [frequentist setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_inference) (like the above), the fairness of a coin is fixed (but unknown); it either is fair or it isn't (so it does not make sense to ask the probability of it being unfair). On the other hand, the [Bayesian setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) [that Matthew Pilling mentions] treats the coin's probability of heads as a random quantity [following some [prior distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) on $[0,1]$], so then it makes sense to talk about the probability of heads. But given that you brought up the binomial test, I am guessing this isn't what you meant to convey.

Comment: My intuition says that I'm looking for a formula that gives a low probability with few throws even if every throw comes up head and a higher probability with more throws.